# How to run yii2mod/yii2-ftp in php 5.5.9?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm try to install yii2 vendor yii2mod/yii2-ftp. But failed cause PHP version in my serve is 5.5.9

Any solution beside update my php to use this vendor ?

```
Problem 1
- phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.3 requires php 5.6 || 7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
- phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.3 requires php 5.6 || 7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
- phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.3 requires php 5.6 || 7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects == 3.4.3.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.3].

$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use lower version, for example **`v1.1`.** It requires **`PHP`** version >= 5.4

Try this link below:

https://www.versioneye.com/php/yii2mod:yii2-ftp/1.1